# Как получить данные из курсора?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Здравствуйте.

Предположим, у меня есть `Cursor`, возвращаемый запросом в БД:

```
        public Cursor getCount(){
        return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT points FROM mytab WHERE _id=1",null);
    }
```

Как мне из курсора получить число и передать это число переменной?

Делаю так:

```
 currentCount = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(points));
```

Выдает ошибку:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
 currentCount = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(points));
}
```

Comment: Сработало, а можете объяснить почему так?

Comment: @Sharlei, потому что в курсоре массив данных из БД, и их нужно по очереди получить (обратиться к каждому и что-то получить), а Вы просто взяли массив из БД и присвоили его int значению.

// если пояснять "в двух словах", то это будет звучать примерно так. Более детально Вы прочтете на develop.android.com, startandroid.ru и других ресурсах в сети Интернет.